# Can a being morph into himself by getting the DNA from his clone or an unattached part of his body (read as "severed limb")?

Tags: animorphs, morphing

Something along the lines of: *Marco -Oh, the iskoorts made a clone with my DNA, let's acquire him so I'll be able to transform into myself.*

Or also: *A dracon beam makes Jake's shoulder explode, effectively severing his right arm but as the controller looses his head thanks to Ax's tailblade, Jake takes the opportunity to acquire his own DNA from his (relatively still living) arm, morph into something to cure his body and back to being Jake with an additional morph of himself.*

Comment: If I understand correctly, your core question is whether they can acquire a morph from only part of an animal?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Not exactly. I'm trying to get aroud the blockage of being only able to get the DNA from an alive being. If Elfangor dying counts as an alive being, then a part of yourself but separate from you dying might be able to serve. As stated some times in the series, a lot of the morphing technology depends on intent and concepts, so I'm trying to stretch the concept of an alive being just this time to overcome the "You can't transform into yourself" problem.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots  Also, when the animorphs transformed into the iskoorts, did they transform into the isks only or into the isk-yoork pair? I'm stretching this analogy to an extreme case where you are only your brain, and your body can be perceived as a separate entity that happens to have your same DNA. But just for the acquisition process, because I suppose you don't want to transform into just your brain when a dracon beam makes a hole in your chest and you want to recover without calling much attention over you.